# What is the meaning of step in ERA reanalysis data?

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, reanalysis, era

The webpage to [download ERA data](http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc) includes an option called "time" which is intuitive, but also an option called "step". I can't find an explanation of the meaning of this. It can't be a time step because it has also 0.

Comment: I suggest editing the question to define the acronym "ERA"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "step" is the number of hours the ERA re-forecast has been run into the future from the "time" of the re-analysis.

For example, asking for ERA data with time = 12:00 and step = 0 means asking for data valid at 12:00 based on a re-analysis for 12:00. But asking for data with time = 12:00 and step = 6 means asking for data valid at 18:00, i.e. for data produced by a 6 h model run based on the 12:00 re-analysis.

To fill the gaps between the analysis times one can use steps from a forward run. Forward runs are needed to get parameters like time accumulated precipitation, which would not be available from an analysis. Sometimes a combination of steps and times might be appropriate for a joint analysis of instantaneous and time averaged parameters, i.e. to stagger them correctly in time.

Data valid 00:00 deviate less from the observations if they come from a 00:00 analysis compared to data from step 12 of the 12:00 analysis. But a series of steps from one initialization time should be more consistent in time compared to a series of independent analyses.

Comment: thank you, it's still somewhat unclear though, all I need is the data at the time it was measured/modelled, what is the purpose of the step, why would someone want to use a step 6 or 12? It would be night instead of day.

Comment: @user4050 e.g. because sometimes it's useful to know the difference between "forecast" and "outturn", and comparing the 00:00 figures with the previous day's 12:00 + 12h forecast is one way to approach that.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers why is it that some variables are not available at 6 and 12 time and not available at step 0?

Comment: I think it could be useful to address the availability of variables in a separate question.

Comment: @user4050 ^ just as BHF says

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion comes from the mixture of analysis data (such as 2m-air temperature) and reanalysis products (such as downward radiation) in the final reanalysis product. The following text directly from ECMWF may help

https://confluence.ecmwf.int/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56658233

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Can you [edit] this and quote the relevant parts here? The text as written now does not seem to answer the question.