# Why is radiation and total precipitation not available in ERA Interim Reanalysis at step 0?

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, reanalysis, era

ERA Interim reanalysis http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc surface level variables such as radiation and precipitation, but also many others, are only available at time 0:00 and 12:00, and not available at step 0? I need 6-hour data and from what I understand regarding the step option, I want step 0 as I need data valid for the same time. [What is the meaning of step in ERA reanalysis data?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/what-is-the-meaning-of-step-in-era-reanalysis-data)

I will use this data in a forest modeling simulation that needs 6-hour data.

Answer (score 5):

The ERA archive description document, Berrisford et al (2011) "[The ERA-Interim archive Version 2.0](http://www.ecmwf.int/en/elibrary/8174-era-interim-archive-version-20)", provides additional information about what is available.  It's less explicit on the why, but we can read between the lines a bit.

The archive consists of re-analyses of the system state at 00, 06, 12, and 18 UTC and re-forecasts out to 10 days initialised from those 00 and 12 UTC states.  Table 9 of that document lists the variables (including the ones that you're interested in) that are stored as accumulations since the start of the re-forecast.  They are stored every 3 hours for the first day of the forecast (steps 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24) less frequently thereafter (every 6 or 12 hours).

**The variables are not stored for step 0 because their accumulations would be exactly zero**.

Regarding using ERA Interim for model forcing, you might consider what [Balsamo et al (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/hess-19-389-2015) do for ERA Land forcing.  They use state variables from steps 3, 6, 9 and 12 and accumulations from steps 12, 15, 18 and 21 (see Fig 1 of that paper).  This inconsistency is because the fluxes (accumulations) are particularly prone to spin-up artefacts in the first few hours of the forecast.  The trade-off is that the states and the fluxes used in the forcing come from slightly different forecasts.